# When adding an item, will deleting the coloumn where we add new data, will it delete the previous data already entered in the records

Tags: column, calculated-column

I have a share point website with a list and important records. However my manager told me to amend the columns, as it's type has also to be changed to choice from Azure AD rather than the single line text. I want to know that if I will delete the columns of the form, will it affect or delete the previously saved records? As I don't want to lose the important records of the company.

Matter is urgent and the support will be really appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it would delete the column and therefore the values for each item for that column.

Additionally, SharePoint won't just let you change a Single Line of Text column to a People Picker column.

Instead, create a new column in the list and if needed use the value of the SLT column to pick the correct person for the new People Picker column. After your boss is satisfied the new column is populated in all items, you can safely delete the old column and no "Knowledge" is lost

Edit - or alternately, set the old column to be hidden from forms and views.